# Creating an array using the elements of an another array

Tags: arrays, logic, combinations

I got the array x=[x₁ x₂ ... xₙ], n can be from 2 to 6.
I want to create an array using m as well as n, m can be up to 20.
If m=1 and n=5 my array would look like this:

```
x= [x₁    x₂    x₃    x₄    x₅]
```

If m=2 n=5

```
a= [x₁    x₂    x₃    x₄    x₅     x₁²    x₂²    x₃²    x₄²    x₅²     x₁⊗x₂    x₁⊗x₃    x₁⊗x₄    x₁⊗x₅        x₂⊗x₃    x₂⊗x₄    x₂⊗x₅        x₃⊗x₄    x₃⊗x₅        x₄⊗x₅]
```

How can I create my array with any n(from 2 to 6) and m (from 1 to 20)?
I must avoid repetitions like the equivalency between x₁⊗x₂ and x₂⊗x₁ .
I'm stuck in the logic, not the code.

Comment: Wondering whether you've made typos in the code samples. Should "a= [1 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5]" instead be "a= [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5]"? What is "x1^2 x2^2 x3^2 x4^2 x5^2"? Wondering whether it shouldn't be there....

Comment: I made a mistake on the initial array, but I edited it.
x1^2 is x1 * x1
x2^2 is x2 * x2 and so on

Comment: I think I understand what is going on when m=2. But I'm finding it hard to extrapolate in a certain way, to the cases where m is higher. Can you please provide more detail as to what happens when m is higher?

Comment: for m=3 in adition to the previous elements of the vector we got x1^3 x2^3... x5^3
and x1^2 * x2 x1^2 * x3 x1^2 *x4. All the unique possible combinations

Comment: Okay, think I understand what all the elements will be for higher m, but not sure how the order is determined. Does the order matter?

Comment: No, the order of the elements in a does not matter